# Core Plot - how to place ticks on top of axis in single quadrant plot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

So I have a single quadrant plot that is working well, except that when a point falls exactly on an axis, it gets cut off.

[image]

The blue and green triangles on the right side of x-axis above should be full diamonds.

Is there any simple way to make the ticks display on top of the x-axis instead of getting cut off? I'd like to keep the origin where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the axes inside the plot area so the plot symbols don't get cut off. The best way to do that is to expand the plot ranges slightly and use the `visibleRange` and `gridLinesRange` properties to limit the visible parts of the axis and grid lines.

The "Control Chart" plot in the *Plot Gallery* example app demonstrates this technique.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Something else to note, that took me a little while to realize, is that you can't use axis constraints with this technique or the constraints will overwrite the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of the points in the "numberForPlot" method used :

If the value equals 0, add something to it in order to have the bottom of the diamond touching the x-axis. The amount you have to add is dependent of your scale and should be calculable programatically.

If you have user interaction in this graph, for example if the user can select a point and show its value, then you should keep a record of the "modified" points, in order to be able to display "real" values.